# Can we use include (”TheWalkin.php”) two times in a PHP page “makeit.PHP”?

Tags: php

I it possible to include two times a page called walkin in a page makeit.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

But the code will be executed twice.

If you only want it to be included once, use the aptly named include_once.

Problems may occur if you define functions or classes or connections twice. Why do you want to include twice?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. PHP's [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) acts like a copy and paste, so your question is equivalent to "Can we copy and paste 'TheWalkin.php' two times in a PHP page?

If there are no function or class definitions in TheWalkin.php, yes.

EDIT: Maybe you want to look at this: [include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php). It makes sure you are only include a file once.